# In Django, if I select_for_update() a particular model instance, will its related model instances be locked as well?

Tags: django

```
my_model_instance = MyModel.objects.select_for_update().get(id=1)
something_related = my_model_instance.related_thing
```

In the above code, `related_thing` is another model instance related to `my_model_instance` by a foreign key.  Since I originally did a `select_for_update()`, will the `related_thing` be locked as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The example you give will make 2 queries:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `mymodel` WHERE `mymodel`.`id` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
SELECT ••• FROM `related_thing` WHERE `related_thing`.`id` = ?;
```

Clearly only the first locks. However, if you use select_related() the single query would be:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `mymodel` LEFT OUTER JOIN `related_thing` ON (`mymodel`.`related_thing_id` = `related_thing`.`id`) WHERE `mymodel`.`id` = 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

In which case it would lock related_thing as well (at least in MySQL but it might be db dependent).